# Function in Package does not return the date,

Tags: oracle, plsql

I will publish the package body and call the function

The function is execute, but does not return data.

Maybe my calling function is bad.

Can you tell me where the error is?

Thanks in advance

My function in package body looks like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY account_api AS
  2      PROCEDURE add_new_account
  3          ( p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
  4          , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
  5           , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
  6           , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type)
  7        IS
  8        BEGIN
  9            INSERT INTO accounts(acc_id, acc_name, acc_amount, acc_date)
 10           VALUES (p_acc_id, p_acc_name, p_acc_amount, p_acc_date);     
 11       COMMIT;
 12        EXCEPTION
 13               WHEN OTHERS THEN
 14               ROLLBACK;
 15              RAISE;
 16      END;
 17       PROCEDURE upd_account
 18          (p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
 19            , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
 20            , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
 21            , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type
 22       )
 23        IS
 24       BEGIN
 25          UPDATE accounts
 26            set acc_name = p_acc_name
 27              , acc_amount = p_acc_amount
 28              , acc_date   = p_acc_date
 29          WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
 30      COMMIT;
 31     END;
 32      PROCEDURE del_accounts
 33         (p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type)
 34      IS  
 35       BEGIN 
 36       DELETE FROM accounts WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
 37      COMMIT;
 38       EXCEPTION
 39         WHEN OTHERS THEN
 40         ROLLBACK;
 41         RAISE;
 42      END;
 43      FUNCTION get_amount
 44         (p_acc_id    accounts.acc_id%type)
 45      return Number is res number;
 46      begin
 47          select acc_amount into res
 48         from  accounts where acc_id =p_acc_id;
 49         return res;
 50     end;
 51     FUNCTION get_date
 52         (p_acc_id    accounts.acc_id%type)
 53      RETURN date IS res1 date;
 54     BEGIN
 55         SELECT acc_date INTO res1
 56         FROM accounts WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
 57         RETURN res1;
 58          end;
 59     end account_api;
 60    /
```

The function is executed but does not return the data.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare 
  2     res1 date;
  3  begin
  4     res1 := account_api.get_date(1);
  5   end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't return data? The anonymous block you've shown isn't doing anything with `res1`. Did you mean to debug with a `dbms_output` call perhaps?

Comment: Yes, as he wrote, Neeraj Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Try to check date by printing. It will show you the output.

```
set serveroutput on
declare 
 res1 date;
 begin
  res1 := account_api.get_date(1);
  dbms_output.put_line(res1);
 end;
 /
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped my

Comment: If this code is useful for you. Kindly rate it so it may help others too. :)